# dismissViewControllerAnimated completion method not working

Tags: objective-c, ios

Here's my app design. I have `mainController` which presents `secondViewController`. Now, I want to dismiss `secondViewController` and subsequently call the method `aMethod` on `mainController` like so:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:aMethod];
```

But this gives me the error `use of undeclared identifier 'aMethod'`

Obviously I am not using the completion handler correctly, but I cannot figure out the correct way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this what you are looking for,

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            [self.mainController aMethod];
        }];
```

In the above code you need to declare `self` outside the block and use it as,

```
__block SecondViewController *object = self;

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
                [object.mainController aMethod];
            }];
```

Just to avoid `self` getting retained in block.

**Update:**

Got the issue now. You need to declare `mainController` as a property in your .h file of `secondViewController`. After that when you are presenting the `secondViewController` from `maincontroller`, you need to set it as,

```
secondViewController.maincontroller = self;
[self presentViewController:secondViewController animated:YES completion:Nil];
```

In your `SecondViewController.h` file,

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) MainController *mainController;
```

In your `SecondViewController.m` file,

```
@synthesis mainController;
```

**Update 2:**

If you do not want to declare `maincontroller` as a property, try this. I am not sure whether this is the right way to do. But it looks like it used to work.

```
 MainController *mainController = (MainController *)[self.view.superview nextResponder];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
                    [mainController aMethod];
                }];
```

**Update 3(Suggested):**

This should work for you. Check it.

```
 MainController *mainController = (MainController *)self.parentViewController;

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
                    [mainController aMethod];
                }];
```

Comment: Well ig im doing `__block YouViewController *object = self` wouldnt i be setting object to be the viewController that is being dismissed? Not the one being presented?

Comment: Oh ok just saw your update. object doesnt have mainController, it doesnt know what it is..

Comment: `secondViewController.maincontroller = self;` line doesnt really make sense as secondviewcontroller does not have maincontroller

Comment: I have updated with 3 different approaches. Try with the last one. You can use it as self.parentViewController. In case that doesn't work try other approaches.

Comment: parentViewController doesnt work but thats an issue with the fact that im using a tabbarcontroller.. im working on update 2

Comment: Update 3 worked for me.  Now I have to figure out why it says aMethod not found.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            ...
            <do something on completion here>
            ...
        }];
```

Comment: same error... which controller receives the method in completion?

Comment: it is a method declared in `mainController` which is the controller being displayed upon calling dismissviewcontrolleranimated

Comment: so you will need something like `[mainController aMethod];` inside the block.

Answer (score -3):

Declare this : `dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil`

I hope it helps.

Comment: No that does not help. Im trying to call a method on the viewController that is going to be displayed once the current one is dismissed... hence my use of completion